# What is this kind art called?

Tags: style-identification, graphic-styles, art, digital, concept-art

There are many different kinds of concept art, but I'm very interested in this style.

What is this style called?
[image: concept art]

art by: Marco Bucci

Comment: Not all art has a "style" name. If anything that *might be* referred to as impressionism.

Comment: I think I'd just call the style concept art. You're right that not all concept art is the same, but it's got that digital painting look and sort of sketch like appearance which makes sense since the point of concept art is to get a point across with as little work as possible (kind of). The theme often dictates the feel of it. Like Pixar concept art would likely never be this dark... Or maybe just to test the limits... But if you look at concept art for nearly any game that's sort of serious, it'll look a lot like this.

Comment: this art is probably just called painting

Answer (score 3):

## Digital Impressionism

I found some similar examples with this name in [DevianArt](https://www.deviantart.com/martanael/gallery/26798096/Digital-Impressionism)

[image]

In [design.tutsplus.com](https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/the-amazing-illustrations-of-marta-de-andres--psd-15089)

[image]

In [artstation.com](https://www.artstation.com/kemonokage)

[image]